# Django - None vs. Null

Tags: python, django

I am setting a ForeignKey to `on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True` But i am confused, I just want that If FK gets deleted, all other relations should stay in db.

is the result of

```
on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
```

and

```
on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None
```

the same for my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This would achieve the same result.

However you should set `null=True` in both examples because it decides whether the field can be NULL at database level.

In first example you don't have a default value. That just means that you have to set the value before you can save the object to a database.

I would go for `on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True`